# Enabling Chrome WebGL inspector causes an error

Tags: google-chrome, textures, glsl, webgl

I have a ThreeJS application which uses a video texture to colour the faces of a cube. It works fine, as long as I don't turn on WebGL inspector.

If I *do* turn on WebGL inspector, the page reloads and the cube shows up as plain black without any texture. In the console, I get the following error message (repeated a couple of hundred times):

> WebGL: drawElements: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not
>   renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture
>   filtering or is not 'texture complete'. Or the texture is Float or
>   Half Float type with linear filtering while OES_float_linear or
>   OES_half_float_linear extension is not enabled.

I don't believe there's anything wrong with the texture. It's definitely a power-of-2, and works fine so long as I don't use the WebGL inspector. Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Comment: I am removing the [tag:google-chrome-extension] tag, since it's not about extension development.

Comment: This should be an issue on the [github page of WebGL Inspector](https://github.com/benvanik/WebGL-Inspector)